JOLT convert nested list into array
I have a JSON formatted payload with nested objects that I want to modify into an array so Nifi can process the array elements pushing them into SQL. Input looks like this:
[
  {
    "architecture": "x64",
    "hostname": "LAPTOP-B442R49A",
    "memory": "32",
    "network0": {
      "asset_id": 1,
      "defaultgateway": "192.168.1.99",
      "dnsserver": "192.168.1.99",
      "ipaddress": "192.168.1.239"
    },
    "network1": {
      "asset_id": 1,
      "defaultgateway": "",
      "dnsserver": "",
      "ipaddress": "192.168.56.1"
    },
    "volume0": {
      "asset_id": 1,
      "caption": "C:\\",
      "freespace": "89"
    },
    "volume1": {
      "asset_id": 1,
      "caption": "D:\\",
      "freespace": "0"
    },
    "asset_id": 1
  }
]

Desired output is:
[
  {
    "architecture": "x64",
    "hostname": "LAPTOP-B442R49A",
    "memory": "32",
    "networks": [
      {
        "name": "network0",
        "asset_id": 1,
        "defaultgateway": "192.168.1.99",
        "dnsserver": "192.168.1.99",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.239"
      },
      {
        "name": "network1",
        "asset_id": 1,
        "defaultgateway": "",
        "dnsserver": "",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.56.1"
      }
    ],
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "volume0",
        "asset_id": 1,
        "caption": "C:\\",
        "freespace": "89"
      },
      {
        "name": "volume1",
        "asset_id": 1,
        "caption": "D:\\",
        "freespace": "0"
      }
    ],
    "asset_id": 1
  }
]

In the end we came up with the following spec (only for volumes):
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "volume*": {
          "caption": "&.description",
          "freespace": "&.capacity_free",
          "name": "&.drive_name",
          "asset_id": "&.asset_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "volumes[]"
    }
  }
]

But that one does not get us what we want. Thanks for any help.

Hope the below Jolt spec will be helpful for you.
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "volume*": {
          "@": "[#3].&1",
          "$": "[#3].&1.name"
        },
        "network*": {
          "@": "[#3].&1",
          "$": "[#3].&1.name"
        },
        "*": "[#].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "volume*": "[&1].volume[]",
        "network*": "[&1].network[]",
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]


You can use separating the literals by asterikses and completing the missing spellings tecnique such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&", // all elements except for "volume" and "network"
        "*rk*": {
          "$": "[&2].&(1,1)rks.[&(1,2)].name", // &(1,2) represents going 1 level 
          // up the tree and grabbing the second replacement of asterisk
          "*": "[&2].&(1,1)rks.[&(1,2)].&"
        },
        "*me*": {
          "$": "[&2].&(1,1)mes.[&(1,2)].name", //  &(1,2) here matches  ordinal  
          // integers such as 0,1..etc.
          "*": "[&2].&(1,1)mes.[&(1,2)].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Thnaks guys. Real life cuaght up with me, so did not have time to test it sooner. Both solutions above work fine. The first one is slightly easier to understand for a n00b like me. Thanks again.
